# Re-including a module on-the-fly

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am currently working on technical debt identified by SonarQube for a Node.js application. My application allows on-the-fly switching between a live and mock datasource. To achieve this I destroy the previous "require" from cache and re-require it. When running SonarQube it does not like "require" statements. It does suggest "import" statements. However that may not be suitable in this case.

Simplified version of existing code:

```
var config = require('../config');
var polService = require(config.polService);
var root = require('../root');
function doingStuff(liveOrMock) {
    setEnvironment(liveOrMock);
    delete require.cache[require.resolve(root.path + ‘/config’)];
    config = require('../config');
    polService = require(config.polService);
}
```

The `setEnvironment` function sets `process.env.NODE_ENV = liveOrMock`, which is used in `config.js`. We export the `config` module using `module.exports = localOptions[process.env.NODE_ENV];` This code picks a single key-pair from a JSON. The value that comes back is used to choose which module is being used for a restService.

Being able to change what module is being used is for `polService` is the purpose of the code.

Comment: Yes, it looks like ES6 modules are not suitable here. They don't allow messing around like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `config` module to export a function, and then call this function whenever you need to change environment.

In order to make `polService` a dynamic module, you can use [dynamic `import()`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import). `import()` is not supported natively, but you can use [this Babel plugin](https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack) (it works with webpack) to transpile it.

`config.js`:

```
export default () => {
  // ...
  return localOptions[process.env.NODE_ENV];
}
```

Main module:

```
import getConfig from '../config';

let config = getConfig();

function doingStuff(liveOrMock) {
  setEnvironment(liveOrMock);
  config = getConfig();
  return import(config.polService).then(result => {
    polService = result;
  });
}
```

Keep in mind that now the `doingStuff` function is asynchronous (i.e. returns a promise), so you can't just call it and access `polService` immediately. You have to wait for it by either using the [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method, or using `await` in an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

If you have a limited number of `polService` modules, it might be a better option to import all of them beforehand, and in the `doingStuff` function just switch which one the `polService` variable refers to.

```
import getConfig from '../config';
import polService1 from '../polService1';
import polService2 from '../polService2';
import polService3 from '../polService3';

const polServices = { polService1, polService2, polService3 };

let config = getConfig();
let polService = polService1;

function doingStuff(liveOrMock) {
  setEnvironment(liveOrMock);
  config = getConfig();
  polService = polServices[config.polService];
}
```